# MongoDB query work but not with Node.js Express Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a date range query which tools several days and there were no answer. i work with node.js express.js MongoDB Mongoose. This query is working perfectly in MongoDB:

```
date =  new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1); 
db.getCollection('c_crimes').find({DateTime:{$gte:date.toISOString(),$lte:new Date().toISOString()}})
```

but this query in my node code and with mongoose with the exact same database and other will return empty array []:

```
 let dayDate = new Date();
 dayDate.setDate(dayDate.getDate() - 1);
 dayDate = dayDate.toISOString();
 await Crimes.find({DateTime: {$gte: dayDate,$lte: new Date().toISOString()}})
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was the data type. in MongoDB, there was no problem with ranging the String date type but in Mongoose is very important to your data type be Date really and that's very important.